# My code for the redisgraph only needed one relationship but it pop out unesessary and duplicate relationship

Tags: database, graph, redis, relationship

GRAPH.QUERY movie_graph 'CREATE (m:Movie {
title:"Top Gun: Maverick",
maincast:"Tom Cruise",
realeased:"2022 MAY",
Best_Quote:"Its not about the plane,its about the pilot."
})'

GRAPH.QUERY movie_graph 'CREATE (a:Actor {
name:"Tom Cruise",
nationality:"American",
Birthdate:"July 3, 1962",
Age:"60"
})'

GRAPH.QUERY movie_graph "MATCH (a:Actor),(m:Movie) CREATE (a)-[r:ACTED_IN {role:'Maverick'}]->(m) Return m,a "

Comment: Running your 3 queries on RedisGraph 2.8.15 - only one relationship is created.

Comment: Why i cant run on redisinsight, is it be cause of limitation?

Comment: Just checked. The third query generates the expected visualization in RedisInsight v2 (2.4)